# NodeJs Objects Merge in key value Id based

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

The Array of objects is differents,

some objects **Module_Id** is same, how to merge same module_Id objects in expected output

```
[{
           "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049b16d0",
           "Create_Permission": false,
           "Edit_Permission": true,
           "View_Permission": true,
           "Delete_Permission": false
       },
       {
           "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049b16d0",
           "Create_Permission": true,
           "Edit_Permission": false,
           "View_Permission": true,
           "Delete_Permission": false
       },
       {
           "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049b16d0",
           "Create_Permission": false,
           "Edit_Permission": false,
           "View_Permission": true,
           "Delete_Permission": true
       },
       {
           "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049bg56d",
           "Create_Permission": false,
           "Edit_Permission": false,
           "View_Permission": false,
           "Delete_Permission": true
       }]
```

My expected Output is:

```
        [{
           "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049b16d0",
           "Create_Permission": true,
           "Edit_Permission": true,
           "View_Permission": true,
           "Delete_Permission": true
       },
       {
         "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049bg56d",
         "Create_Permission": false,
         "Edit_Permission": false,
         "View_Permission": false,
         "Delete_Permission": true
       }]
```

I am using NodeJs and ES6 javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Array.reduce()`:

```js
var array = [{
           "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049b16d0",
           "Create_Permission": false,
           "Edit_Permission": true,
           "View_Permission": true,
           "Delete_Permission": false
       },
       {
           "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049b16d0",
           "Create_Permission": true,
           "Edit_Permission": false,
           "View_Permission": true,
           "Delete_Permission": false
       },
       {
           "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049b16d0",
           "Create_Permission": false,
           "Edit_Permission": false,
           "View_Permission": true,
           "Delete_Permission": true
       },
       {
           "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049bg56d",
           "Create_Permission": false,
           "Edit_Permission": false,
           "View_Permission": false,
           "Delete_Permission": true
}];
var res = array.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
  let existObj = acc.find(({Module_Id}) =>  Module_Id == obj.Module_Id);
  if(existObj){
     existObj.Create_Permission = existObj.Create_Permission || obj.Create_Permission;
     existObj.Edit_Permission = existObj.Edit_Permission || obj.Edit_Permission;
     existObj.View_Permission = existObj.View_Permission || obj.View_Permission;
     existObj.Delete_Permission = existObj.Delete_Permission || obj.Delete_Permission;
     return acc;
   }
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` with `Object.values()`

```js
const data = [{ "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049b16d0", "Create_Permission": false, "Edit_Permission": true, "View_Permission": true, "Delete_Permission": false }, { "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049b16d0", "Create_Permission": true, "Edit_Permission": false, "View_Permission": true, "Delete_Permission": false }, { "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049b16d0", "Create_Permission": false, "Edit_Permission": false, "View_Permission": true, "Delete_Permission": true }, { "Module_Id": "5b3c8f83f632ce0b049bg56d", "Create_Permission": false, "Edit_Permission": false, "View_Permission": false, "Delete_Permission": true }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.Module_Id] = o.Module_Id in r ?  Object.keys(r[o.Module_Id]).reduce((res,k) => {
          res[k] = r[o.Module_Id][k] || o[k];
          return res;
        },{}) : o;
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: i expected output not get from your solution

Comment: Updated the solution.